# CAS authentication with Play framework

Tags: authentication, playframework-2.0, cas

I need to use CAS to authorize access to a web application built with the Play! 2.x framework.  Play! 1.x has a module for CAS  (http://www.playframework.org/modules/cas);  Play! 2.x does not (that I've been able to find).

Does anyone have sample code they would be willing to share?  Tips/tricks/gotchas?  Otherwise, I'll dig into the 1.x module and see if I can adapt it to work with 2.x.

I'm developing with Scala.

Thanks,
Byron

[Update]
I also asked this on the Play! google group.  James Roper replied to say:

> Well, Play 2 is quite different from Play 1, so don't expect it to be easy to port.  You have two general approaches:
>
> 1) The easy but not as good approach, use the official CAS Java client to make blocking calls on the CAS server.  Make sure your Akka thread pools are tuned for this, by default they give you one thread per core, if you go with this approach you probably want 100-200 threads all up, otherwise other requests are going to get blocked by requests that are trying to talk to the CAS server, especially if the CAS server is ever slow to repsond.
>
> 2) The hard but better approach, implement your own non blocking CAS client using the Play WS API.  The protocol is described here: http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol

My current thought is to put an Apache server in front of Play to do the CAS authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I've created what you're looking for : a Play 2.x client in Scala and Java which supports OAuth/CAS/OpenID/HTTP authentication and user profile retrieval : https://github.com/leleuj/play-pac4j.

It completely supports the CAS protocol :

- CAS 1.0 / 2.0 / SAML valition + proxy ticket validation
- logout request
- CAS proxification

Comment: Does this plugin support X.509 Certificate Support ?

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion, but no. It would certainly make sense to add that support in the module : https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j/tree/master/pac4j-http. That said, CAS server supports X509 certificate and play-pac4j supports CAS server.